# ¿Como se ponen negritas parciales con Apache POI? (Documento word)

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-poi

Recientemente he estado trabajando en un proyecto para hacer documentos Word y decidi usar Apache POI
Pero me tope con un problema y es de en un mismo parrafo existan negritas a la vez que texto normal por ejemplo: "Hola **Mundo**"

```
    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
    String ruta = System.getProperty("user.home")+ "/Desktop/"+ contenido.get(0);
    ruta = ruta.replace("\\","/");
            
    XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
    XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
    String str1 = "BUENO POR ";
    run.setText(str1);
    String str2 = contenido.get(1); //Texto que debe de estar en negritas
    run.setText(str2);
    run.setBold(true);
    run.setFontSize(9);
    run.setFontFamily("Arial");
    
    paragraph.setSpacingBetween(1);
    paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.RIGHT);
    try {
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(ruta);
        document.write(output);
        output.close();
        document.close();
    }catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Favor de cerrar otros documentos word");
    }
```

Tengo entendido que el "run.setBold(true)" afecta a todo el parrafo pero ocupo que solamente una parte del texto este en negrita